# get all youtube videos that a user has liked on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql

What I need, through the facebook API, is to get (for a specific, logged user) all the youtube videos (links to youtube pages) she liked on facebook, meaning all the posts she liked that contained a link to a youtube video.

I know I can do that in FQL with the url_like table, but I'd like to also have access to **when** the user liked the link (or at least when the link was posted), and more in general have access to the post it liked the video on.

For reference, this is the FQL documentation for that table (which does not serve the purpose):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/

Answer (score 5):

The call is very complex and I'm not really sure where to begin fixing the performance, maybe some batch calls, saving of data to post process... but the actual call itself using purely FQL takes a long time or chokes out on too big a query.

```
SELECT link_id, owner, created_time, title, summary, url, picture, image_urls 
FROM link 
WHERE url in 
    (SELECT url, user_id 
     FROM url_like 
     WHERE user_id=me()
     AND strpos(url, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=') >= 0)
AND owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() LIMIT 20)
```

Notice I imposed a limit of 20 friends.

Comment: interesting.. this clearly doesn't work as it is but could be improved.. maybe doing batch on the created_time and doing a week at a time?

Comment: @luca something like that, the query is hitting three tables, FQL is unstable as it is, in theory it's correct, actual results may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not use:

{userId}/likes?fields=created_time.

For example, if I use "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?fields=created_time" it gives me my likes and the times I liked them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do likes include link likes? I think they're only likes to facebook stuff (posts, pictures, pages... )

Comment: Hi @luca `[userid]/likes?fields=created_time,link,website` will show the link likes and website associated with this page.

Comment: yeah, but in my case it's like on posts that contained links.. this will not work

Comment: @luca Facebook doesn't offer time when use liked an URL. And I don't think they will be giving it in future. It comes under Facebook privacy policy. There is a smiliar post on this at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417918/facebook-find-out-when-user-liked-an-url

Comment: well, if that is the case (I'm not convinced I need to check better) the time could be the creation date of the post containing the link, that's not a big deal