# How to get the facebook user id that likes my website (not a facebook site)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am making a raffle within the people that had make an "I like" to a certain article of my external website (non facebook).  In order to choose the winner I need to know who has made the I like.

This query:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='myWEBSITE'&format=json
Only get me the total count of I Likes but not the users ID

This query is perfect:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20user_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20object_id%3D%MY_object_ID&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

But how do I get an OBJECTID for an external url??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Object can be any thing like video, note, link, photo, or album but can not be any FB page or Url.. So I guess its not possible to get the user Id for a URL.

If you are using JS SDK / Like plugin in your website to like it, i think you can subscribe to an event and then use some ajax calls to get those userIds whenever they instantly like it.

See Somnath Muluk's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13467793/269521